# Using an object as parameter in a React Function Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wasn't able to find an answer for this.
I'm using TS to build some Components in React, the thing is I'm working with Component Framework and whenever I try to send the props to a Function Component, if I try to use them, I get the next error:

`Property 'text' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.`

The code is like this:
The props declaration:

```
    public props: IFirstButton = {
        text: "",
        entity: "",
        selectedField: "",
        context: null,
        onChangeText: this.onChangeText.bind(this)
    };
```

Here is the calling to the Component:

```
        ReactDom.render(
            React.createElement(AppComponentExample, this.props),
            this._container
        )
```

The Component calling Function Component:

```
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <React.Fragment> 
            <PanelBasicExample {...this.props} ></PanelBasicExample>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
```

And finally, the Function Component:

```
export const PanelBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, { setTrue: openPanel, setFalse: dismissPanel }] = useBoolean(false);
  const searchText: any = "Selector Cuenta Bancaria" || props.text;
  console.log(props);
  const panelStyles: Partial<IPanelStyles> = {
    main: {
        alignContent: "center",
        '@media(min-width: 480px)': {
        width: "100%",
        position: "absolute",
        overflow: "hidden auto",
      }
    },
    header: {
      width: "100%",
      textAlign: "center"
    }
  }
  const panelStyle = {
    height: "80%",
    left: "25%",
    right: "25%"
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultButton text={searchText} onClick={openPanel} />
      <Panel
        headerText="Selector Cuenta Bancaria"
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onDismiss={dismissPanel}
        // You MUST provide this prop! Otherwise screen readers will just say "button" with no label.
        closeButtonAriaLabel="Cerrar"
        style={panelStyle}
        styles={panelStyles}
      >
        <TableExample {...props}></TableExample>
      </Panel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

PD: That console log logs what I'm expecting (the correct object with the data I need)

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Whenever I try to use a property from the props in the Function Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is most likely is the type declarations with the `DefaultButton`  component(which you did not provide in the question code).

```
   <DefaultButton text={searchText} onClick={openPanel} />
```

add text:string to the props DefaultButton accepts.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help! The Default Button is from the Fluent UI, that's why I didn't provide the code.
Because of this, I can't change the props DefaultButton accepts.

Comment: Got it, try 'npm install @types/<theLibName>', sometimes when using typescript you need to the download the types defenitions in addition to the normal package